# how to use promises and services in angularjs to add a number

Tags: angularjs

use 3 services for passing two numbers and a sum of them. Then pass to controllers to print the sum of random numbers.
I used this. but need to use promises and services.

```
app.service("Service",function(){
  this.number = function(a) {
            return a;
        }
  });

    app.service("Service1",function(){
  this.number = function(b) {
            return b;
        }
  });
  app.service("Service2",function(){
  this.addition = function(a+b) {
            return a+b;
        }
  });
app.controller("Controller",function($scope, Service,Service1,Service2){
$scope.result = Service.addition(5,6);
    });
```

Comment: why do you need 3 services, addition of a number can be achieved just using a single service?

Comment: yes i know. But my mentor asked me to do this example. And i am stuck. I have to use 3 services and then return random numbers for addition(using math.random()).

Answer (score 0):

Above scenario can also be achieved using a single service as below

```
app.service("addservice",function(){
this.addition = function(num1, num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, addservice) {
$scope.result =addservice.addition(7,6);
});
```

However, if you want to use promise to make it a async call then it should be like below

```
app.service("addservice",function($q){
this.addition = function(num1, num2) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var result = num1 + num2
        deferred.resolve(result)
        //return promise
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, addservice) {
 addservice.addition(6,6).then(function (data){
   $scope.result = data;
 })
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But i have to do in that way only. Using 3 services and then returning random numbers for addition(using math.random). I am stuck.